# How can you enable forms scripting for outlook 2010 on Citrix servers?

Tags: outlook, citrix, vbscript

I'd like to deploy Office 2010 on Citrix servers, but i can't enable form scripting support.

With outlook 2007, it was solved by adding Outlvbs.dll in the office directory, and running

`msiexec /i {<Outlook GUID>} ADDLOCAL=OutlookVBScript /qb`

But it seems this does not work anymore with Outlook 2010, I get the following error :

`Error 2711. An internal error has occured. (OutlookVBScript).`

I don't get much help from microsoft support site, as there isn't a lot of informations on office 2010 yet.
Have anyone succeded in installing and using outlook 2010 with form scripting in a citrix environment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

msiexec /i {90140000-0011-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE} ADDLOCAL=OutlookVBScript /qb

Windows 2008 R2 with Office 2010 Pro,

Comment: msiexec /i {90140000-003D-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE} ADDLOCAL=OutlookVBScript /qb

Windows 2003 R2 SP2 Terminal servers with Office 2010 Standard